# Explode foreach to new array

Tags: php, arrays, json, explode

I have JSON API response which look something like this

```
Array
(
    [sections] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 115000089967
                    [url] => xxxxx
                    [html_url] => ArticleHTML1
                    [category_id] => 204458828
                    [position] => 0
                    [sorting] => manual
                    [created_at] => 2016-12-19T14:56:23Z
                    [updated_at] => 2017-02-03T08:23:04Z
                    [name] => ArticleName1
                    [description] => 
                    [outdated] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 207077828
                    [url] => xxxxxx
                    [html_url] => ArticleHTML2
                    [category_id] => 204458828
                    [position] => 1
                    [sorting] => manual
                    [created_at] => 2016-11-14T09:28:30Z
                    [updated_at] => 2017-02-02T09:15:42Z
                    [name] => ArticleName2
                    [description] => 
                    [outdated] => 
                )
        )

    [page] => 1
    [per_page] => 30
    [page_count] => 1
    [sort_by] => position
    [sort_order] => asc
)
```

I have successfully iterated this with foreach, so return looks like this:

ArticleName1 ArticleHTML1

ArticleName2 ArticleHTML2

So I took [name] and [html_url] from each like this:

```
$details1 = array('name');
$details2 = array('html_url');

foreach($sections['sections'] as $article) {
  foreach($details1 as $detail) {
    echo "$article[$detail] ";
  }
    foreach($details2 as $detail) {
    echo "$article[$detail]\n";
  }
}
```

But what I want next is that, that response should be exploded to one single array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ArticleName1 ArticleHTML1
    [1] => ArticleName2 ArticleHTML2
)
```

I already managed to explode those to individual arrays:

```
foreach($sections['sections'] as $article) {
  foreach($details1 as $detail) {
    $name = "$article[$detail] ";
  }
    foreach($details2 as $detail) {
    $url = "$article[$detail]\n";
  }
  $string = $name . $url;
  $array = explode(' ', $string, 1);
  print_r($array);
}
```

but I need just one array.

How? I'm lost or just doesn't understand, am I even close?

**EDIT**

The thing here is that the JSON dump is pretty large and I only need few things (name and url). So I was thinking that I first grab the whole thing, then I just take the names and urls (like the first **foreach** is doing), and then put those back to array. Because from those names and urls I need only last 12 keys, and taking those from sinlge array would be easy.

Tho it would be perfect, if I could sort out the keys which I don't want, in the first place. That would solve my problem. Then I wouldn't need a new array etc.

Comment: I don't see why you merge and then immediately explode `$string`? Also the way how you're using foreach is very flawed - `$name` and `$url` will only be the last one etc.

Comment: True. The thing here is that the JSON dump is pretty large and I only need few things (name and url). So I was thinking that I first grab the whole thing, then sort out those what I want, and then put them together. 

Because from those I need only last 12 keys. It would be perfect, if I could sort out the keys which I don't want, in the first place. That would solve my problem. Then I wouldn't need a new array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're making this much more difficult than it needs to be. It's just a single loop:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($sections['sections'] as $article) {
    $array[] = $article['name'] . ' ' . $article['html_url'];
}
```

Comment: This is making arrays in a array. I just want one array where one value is ArticleName1 ArticleHTML1

Comment: and you are missing a semicolon :) I had this already, but now the need is different.

I added some details to original question.

Comment: OK, I've changed it to use concatenation instead of creating an array. But your code then uses `explode()`, which will turn it back into an array. Why not just keep it as an array the whole time?

Comment: And what happens if the name has a space in it?

Comment: Came up also with the concatenation, and works nicely if name has spaces, thanks, got good double check here. Now I need to strip out first four keys and "pretty"print only keys from 4-16. Then I will put them to HTML list and I'm all set.

Comment: Code looks like this now:

`$array = array();
foreach ($sectionsArticles['articles'] as $article) {
    $array[] = array($article['name'] . " " . $article['html_url']);
}

foreach($array as $d){
  foreach($d as $v){
    echo $v."\n";
  }
}`

Comment: Why are you putting them in an array if there's only one element?

Comment: Thought that it would be easier to sort our the needed keys and values. Can I do it easily at the foreach ?

Comment: Used array_slice on the foreach, which I use to "pretty"print the result. This suits me now, don't know if this is the most efficient way to do this, but luckily we are not dealing with huge amount of data.
--
Was thinking that could this be done with regexp or similar? Like in this case the name of the article starts always with the same syntax. This way I wouldn't need to mind if I add more articles to the list. I would always get all the right articles. In Python it was fairly easy.

Comment: I'm sorry about the monologue. Came up with this - `preg_match($pattern, $v, $results);  echo "{$results[0]}\n";` -- This goes inside the last `foreach`. I guess it isn't flawless because I get `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0` of those keys which doesn't include the right word.

Comment: I really don't understand what problem you're trying to solve with all these ways of putting the data together and then pulling it apart again. Why not just keep it in the original associative arrays?